# Getting "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 exception" only when running Spring projects

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

The JDK and JRE in both the project and Eclipse are set to Java 1.7.

I tried executing a simple Hello World project that doesn't use Spring and it runs fine with no Exceptions.

I'm sure the problem is caused by Spring. 
This is the actual Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: change the dependency

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using Spring 5 which requires java 8 (52.0 is the class file version used by java 8.), so try with Spring 4.

In case you use using Spring Boot, use Spring Boot 1.5.13